# Parse custom format to array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to convert a custom formatted .txt file to an array.

Here's a sample of the first lines:

```
[LINETYPE]S [STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]There For You    [PERFORMER]Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan  [MUSICID]21120  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Shut Up and Dance    [PERFORMER]Walk The Moon    [MUSICID]20634  [LABEL]
```

This keeps going, with a new [LINETYPE]S for each hour of the day.

Now, what I want to achieve, is to make an array for each hour - each value containing another array with the brackets as keys:

```
array("00:00:00" => array(

          array("LINETYPE" => "M",
          "TITLE" => "There For You",
          "PERFORMER" => "Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan",
          "MUSICID" => "21120",
          "LABEL" => ""),

           array("LINETYPE" => "M",
          "TITLE" => "Shut Up And Dance",
          "PERFORMER" => "Walk The Moon",
          "MUSICID" => "20634",
          "LABEL" => "")
   ), "01:00:00" => array(
   [...]
);
```

The regex to search for each hour should be correct, but it seems like preg_split does not support multiple capturing groups.

All of the answers I've found so far are on a much more basic level, like exploding a comma.

Here's my code so far.

```
$test = get_musiclog("06082017");

$hours = array();

$regex = "(\[LINETYPE\]S\t\[STARTTIME\])((?:(?:[0-2][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?)?)\n";

if (preg_match_all ("/".$regex."/is", $test, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[2] as $hour) {
        $hours[$hour] = ""; // Music array
    }
}
```

Barely have any hair left after scratching my head thinking about these questions. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

- How can I split the string with "[LINETYPE]S [STARTTIME]**XX:XX:XX**" and keep the time as key?
- How do I split the rest of the elements, knowing that the structure is [key]value\t and \n is the delimiter?
- Is "arrays within arrays within arrays" the right practice at all?

Comment: Don't build a pattern to match all, read the file by block using *stream_get_line* with the string `[LINETYPE]S` (for example) as third parameter.

Comment: Not sure that `"LINETYPE" => "M"` is a pertinent information to keep, it seems it is more related to the file format itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach uses mostly negated character classes to capture values between the tags.  To keep the regex pattern relatively light, optional capture groups are used so that short lines like `LINETYPE S` still match.

Code: ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZlG1M/3)) ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eff99496435d09f34066ea30f23521c2fd0b6eb7))

```
$input='[LINETYPE]S [STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]There For You    [PERFORMER]Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan  [MUSICID]21120  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Shut Up and Dance    [PERFORMER]Walk The Moon    [MUSICID]20634  [LABEL] 
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Subeme La Radio  [PERFORMER]Enrique Iglesias [MUSICID]21105  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]C [TITLE]AUTO S2 NON STOP [PERFORMER] [MUSICID]A2-6   [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Uptown Funk  [PERFORMER]Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars [MUSICID]20533  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Let It Go    [PERFORMER]James Bay    [MUSICID]20839  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]S [STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]There For You    [PERFORMER]Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan  [MUSICID]21120  [LABEL]     
[LINETYPE]M [TITLE]Shut Up and Dance    [PERFORMER]Walk The Moon    [MUSICID]20634  [LABEL]     ';
$pattern='/\[LINETYPE\]([A-Z])\s\[(?:TITLE|STARTTIME)\]([^[\s]*(?: [^[\s]+)*)(?:\s*\[PERFORMER\]([^[ ]*(?: [^[ ]+)*)\s+\[MUSICID\]([^[ ]+)\s+\[LABEL\](\S*(?: \S+)*))?/';
if(!preg_match_all($pattern,$input,$out, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    echo 'something went wrong';
}else{
    foreach($out as $a){
        if($a[1]=='S'){
            $time=$a[2];
        }else{
            $result[$time][]=["LINETYPE"=>$a[1],"TITLE"=>$a[2],"PERFORMER"=>$a[3],"MUSICID"=>$a[4],"LABEL"=>$a[5]];
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '00:00:00' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'There For You',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan',
      'MUSICID' => '21120',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'Shut Up and Dance',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Walk The Moon',
      'MUSICID' => '20634',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'Subeme La Radio',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Enrique Iglesias',
      'MUSICID' => '21105',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'C',
      'TITLE' => 'AUTO S2 NON STOP',
      'PERFORMER' => '',
      'MUSICID' => 'A2-6',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'Uptown Funk',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Mark Ronson & Bruno Mars',
      'MUSICID' => '20533',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'Let It Go',
      'PERFORMER' => 'James Bay',
      'MUSICID' => '20839',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
  ),
  '01:00:00' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'There For You',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Martin Garrix & Troye Sivan',
      'MUSICID' => '21120',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'LINETYPE' => 'M',
      'TITLE' => 'Shut Up and Dance',
      'PERFORMER' => 'Walk The Moon',
      'MUSICID' => '20634',
      'LABEL' => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This helps me a long way, thank you! I tried running the entire log, and found that if there is no PERFORMER set, something weird happens with the array and it throws some "Undefined offset" errors. An example on line 6 [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4006fcc4e70a51669e76074fc20201e1568cb7ec).

Comment: Sorry, wrong formatting in my original post. Each entry is on separate lines.

Comment: I've fed it with all possible log outputs, it works like a charm! Thank you!